# Slide in border from left to right, when hovering UL menu

Tags: html, css, border

I want this border to slide in from left to right(dropmenus only). But can't figure it out

This is how I got so far, I don't have any ideas no more.

Menu is built with ul and li-s.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

```css
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}
.toggle_menu,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}
nav:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}
nav ul {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
nav ul li.active_link a{
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 font-weight:600;
}
nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 }
nav a {
 display:block;
     padding: 14px 16px;
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 font-weight:400;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover { /*background: #000000; */}
nav a:hover { 
 /*background-color: #000000;*/ 
}
nav ul li ul{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
   color: #31302B;
    background: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #b6945d;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
 transition: all ease 1s;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
    box-shadow: inset 900px 0px 0px #b6945d;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
nav ul ul li {
     background-color: transparent;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px;
 left:170px; 
}
nav ul li ul li a{
    font-style: italic;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover{
 font-style:italic;
 color:#b6945d;
}
/*li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }*/
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }
```

```html
        <nav>
        <label for="drop" class="toggle_menu"><img src="assets/images/mobile_button.png"></label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="active_link">
     <a href="#">Avaleht</a>
    </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Kunstnik</label><a href="#">Kunstnik</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Kunstnikust</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tööde arhiiv</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
                <li>
     <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">E-pood</label><a href="#">E-pood</a>
     <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kõik tooted</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seeriatooted</a></li>
     </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have added 10 line css below: Are you looking for this:

```css
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}
.toggle_menu,
[id^=drop] {
 display: none;
}
nav:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}
nav ul {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }
nav ul li.active_link a{
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 font-weight:600;
}
nav ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 }
nav a {
 display:block;
     padding: 14px 16px;
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 font-weight:400;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover { /*background: #000000; */}
nav a:hover { 
 /*background-color: #000000;*/ 
}
nav ul li ul{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
   color: #31302B;
    background: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #b6945d;
 -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
 -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
 transition: all ease 1s;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
    box-shadow: inset 900px 0px 0px #b6945d;
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display:inherit;
}
nav ul ul li {
     background-color: transparent;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul ul li {
 position: relative;
 top:-60px;
 left:170px; 
}
nav ul li ul li a{
    font-style: italic;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover{
 font-style:italic;
 color:#b6945d;
}
/*li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }*/
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }




/**New css for transition**/
nav ul li ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
nav ul li ul:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <label for="drop" class="toggle_menu"><img src="assets/images/mobile_button.png"></label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="active_link">
     <a href="#">Avaleht</a>
    </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Kunstnik</label><a href="#">Kunstnik</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Kunstnikust</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tööde arhiiv</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
                <li>
     <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">E-pood</label><a href="#">E-pood</a>
     <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kõik tooted</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Seeriatooted</a></li>
     </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Almost, but this line should show up when hovering  "Kunstnik" or "E-pood"

Answer (score 0):

Now it works.

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.menu ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.menu > li > ul.sub_menu {
  min-width: 10em;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu ul li { padding: 0px; }
.menu ul li.active a{
 font-weight:600;
}
.second_menu ul li.active a{
 font-weight:600;
}
.menu > ul > li { display: inline-block; }
.menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
 font-family: 'Lato';
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:14px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menu ul li.hover > a {
  color: black;
}

.menu ul li > a { padding: 15px; }

.menu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width:auto;
  background: white;
}
.menu ul li.active_drop a{
 font-weight:600 !important;
 color:#b6945d;
}
.menu ul li ul.dropdown_nav li a{
 font-weight:400;
}
.menu ul li.active_drop a:hover{
 color:#b6945d;
}
.menu ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
.menu ul ul > li { 
 position: relative; 
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
.menu ul ul > li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: auto;
  background: white;
  font-style:italic;
}

.menu ul ul > li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.menu ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}


/* animating the golden border */
.dropdown_nav {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown_nav:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #b6945d;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform .5s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.menu>ul>li:hover .dropdown_nav:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="menu">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">leht</a></li>
        <li class="active">
       <a href="#">leht1</a>
       <ul class="dropdown_nav">
         <li class="dropdown_first active_drop">
                  <a href="#">leht1.1</a></li>
         <li class="dropdown_last"><a href="#">leht1.2</a></li>
       </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
       <a href="#">leht2</a>
       <ul class="dropdown_nav">
         <li class="dropdown_first"><a href="#">leht2.1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">leht2.2</a></li>
       </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">leht3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">leht4</a></li>
      </ul>
       </nav>
```